# Why is there no "Euro English" locale?

Tags: locale, i18n

I used to use the somewhat whimsical `en_DK.UTF-8` locale when installing a new system because that would produce (roughly) the locale results I wanted, even though I am not in Denmark.

- Measurements metric
- Sensible date and time formats, but day and month names in English

  - 24-hour time format
  - Work week starts on Monday
  - Numeric date in (something at least resembling) ISO format, yyyy-mm-dd
  - Informal date is dd/mm, not the other way around
- A4 paper size
- Euro currency
- System messages in English

Alas, Ubuntu and Debian no longer seem to support the `en_DK` locale.  I have been thinking there should be something like `en_EU` for "Euro English".

Every place I have worked has had this sort of requirement -- the official language of the organization is English, but we want continental European defaults for everything else.

I am imagining I am not the first person to think that a "location agnostic" English locale would benefit both me personally and the organizations I work for.  So why does it not exist, and where do I look for further discussions and rationale?

... Or should I go ahead and propose it?  To whom?

Comment: I'm sure this would be a good question somewhere on the StackExchange network, but it's not really a programming problem, is it?

Comment: You get me confused here. Denmark has never adopted the Euro AFAIK, and both Debian testing and unstable still have a en_DK locale (with DKK/kr currency)

Comment: Actually I had just lived with the fact that it had the wrong currency; I don't really need that feature, but it came up as one of the things to include in the question for completeness' sake.  This `en_DK` locale is a weird curiosity; where did it originate, and why are there not random English locales for other countries?  It's hardly like Denmark has an unusually high ratio of English speakers.

Comment: Locales were created for language/nation combo's and not for political or geographical groups of nations.  If they derive from the 'nation' standard, people will be requesting 'spanish/NorthAmerica' or 'english/cree' (Indian tribe) or stuff like that.  They'll totally lose control.

Comment: @Jeach: who would lose control? Over what? Is that a bad thing? Why is a soverign state a good, and/or the only acceptable stakeholder for this? Spanish settings for North America sounds fairly analogous to my scenario; I'm pretty sure there would be a demand for that. And I don't see why the Cree scenario should be ruled out, either, although a real-world demand would be a sensible requirement from a standardizing body.

Comment: Er um, except es_US and es_CA should be distinct, but I guess that's not what you were getting at? In fact I think I have seen es_US somewhere.

Comment: @tripleee: It's just that how would you determine hierarchy?  Is 'en_NA' go before 'en_US' or after in the resolution path?  Does 'en/cree' go after or before 'en_US'?  Only having language/nation, we know what to expect, introducing others could become quite 'out of control' as I mentioned (but that's only my opinion).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where does a hierarchy exist? I'm fine with a web site or application having a default for my territory, but if I want messages in Esperanto and a Mayan calendar and Roman numbers for my own convenience or amusement, it would be nice if they were available as options.

Comment: A "universal English" locale would also be useful as a default for territories for which no other default is available (e.g. Antarctica, or if you don't have translations etc. for a territory like Greenland or Bhutan).

Comment: @tripleee: What I mean by 'hierarchy' is the order in which the records in locals are resolved.

Comment: I sympathise, but I'm also amused that you're spelling 'organisation' with spelling specific to two or three countries (e.g. en_US, maybe en_CA), and not the way most English speakers would internationally.

The real solution, IMHO, is to have separate settings for different contexts. For example, when I live in the US, I prefer to use normal English and standard measurements, but US paper sizes. The fact that USAns call their oddball measurements 'English' does add confusion, though—the English have been using mostly metric for decades, and many of their units differed from the US.

Comment: You may also be interested in `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673886/what-is-the-difference-between-c-utf-8-and-en-us-utf-8-locales/61064759#61064759.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Actually "organization' can be considered en-GB-Oxendict (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling), which is widely used internationally. There is also a UN organization called International Labour Organization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Labour_Organization). Note the "-our" and "-zation".

Comment: % sudo localedef -i ./en_SE -f UTF-8 en_SE.UTF-8
[error] LC_IDENTIFICATION: unknown standard `en_SE:2000' for category `LC_CTYPE'
[error] LC_IDENTIFICATION: unknown standard `en_SE:2000' for category `LC_NUMERIC'
[error] LC_IDENTIFICATION: unknown standard `en_SE:2000' for category `LC_TIME'
(... etc. ...)

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. Are you trying to complain that this locale definition is not available out of the box, or are you trying to report a bug against the custom en_SE package advertised in one of the answers? Either way, commenting on the _question_ doesn't seem like a useful thing to do.

Comment: @tripleee  Yeah, I meant to comment on one of the answers.  Between having to login and copy-paste the results, it somehow got in the wrong submission box.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(a) An entity known as the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org) seems to be the place that handles locales. The glibc wiki indicates that [they will follow CLDR](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales).

(b) They have a locale known as "en_150" which seems to be intended to do what you want. I'm not sure glibc has implemented it yet. There's also a similar locale known as en_BE which is identical to en_150 except that it has regional coverage of BE rather than worldwide.

Comment: [Here is "150" in the Locale Data Explorer](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=150)

Comment: Interesting but I have tried `export LC_TIME=en_150.UTF-8` (and en_BE) on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS and it displays `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_150.UTF-8): No such file or directory`

Answer (score 104):

`en_IE.UTF-8` English (Ireland) locale has nearly all the things you're asking for:

- Measurements metric — **yes**
- 24-hour time format — **yes**
- Work week starts on Monday — **yes**
- Numeric date in (something at least resembling) ISO format, yyyy-mm-dd
  — **no**, it this locale it's `dd/mm/yy`. But that seems close enough to what you're used to
- Informal date is dd/mm, not the other way around  — **yes**
- A4 paper size — **yes**
- Euro currency — **yes**
- System messages in English — **yes**

I'm actually using this locale, even though I'm in Amsterdam, as there is no English (Paneuropean) locale that I know of.

BTW. don't make the mistake of selecting the `ga_IE.UTF-8` Irish (Ireland) locale, as it's Irish Gaelic language.

Comment: Ah, the good old Irish! Great find.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it solves the problem to my complete satisfaction.  I'd still like to find pointers to whether a "universal English" locale has been proposed in the past, and/or where such a proposal should be sent.  The library standardization process part of this question is the reason I originally posted it to PSE, but I don't know if it's suitable there (or anywhere else in the *SE network).

Comment: @tripleee: only thing that like that, which comes to mind is Windows 98 Pan-European version, which was in English, but with European locale and support for European characters. I've not heard of any attempt to create official Pan-Euro locale.

Comment: I have typed command "sudo update-locale LANG=en_IE.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX" and after reboot, when you reply to an email with Thunderbird, it will use standard dd/mm/yy and not yyyy-mm-dd (I tried with Ubuntu 14.04 and Thunderbird 31.1.2).

Comment: A universal English locale might need to consider the thousands separate. Yes, all (native) English speakers use the comma (I think?), but many Europeans use a period (`.`) even when writing English. I'm beginning to be convinced that the apostrophe `'` (used by the Swiss), with `.` for the fractional part, would be a good candidate. It works in csv files and I'm not aware of anywhere that uses `'` for fractional numbers.

Comment: Update to my last comment: to display ISO 8601 dates (yyyy-mm-dd) in Thunderbird on Linux, you can use LC_TIME=en_DK.utf8 in /etc/default/locale http://kb.mozillazine.org/Date_display_format

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the Irish do not use the comma (,) decimal separator, as the rest of the continental Europe.

Comment: Great find! Props also for the decimal dot, to avoid breaking Excel and other programs that would otherwise break horribly whenever numeric data is pasted or read from text files. (the EU should officially switch to dot too, like the rest of the world, also in numpad keymaps)

Answer (score 19):

The en_DK locale doesn't really have anything to do with Denmark except for its name. It was originally created by someone who wanted the same thing as requested here - a reasonable set of defaults for an English speaker in Europe. The name "en_DK" is sort of a joke - all locale names at that time were composed of a language code and a country code (there were no continent codes or anything else in the second position), and for whatever reason Denmark was chosen as the placeholder country code. (... and has probably caused more than one mystified person since then to research the proportion of people in Denmark whose first language is English. :) )

Comment: Do you have a source for DK having been chosen whimsically? (I do agree it's the only locale out there with reasonable settings...)

Comment: Agree that this answer would benefit from at least anecdotal pointers for further research. But thanks for this tidbit already.

Comment: Apparently there's actually [en_DK locale in unicode](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=en_DK)

Comment: The only problem is that it uses DKK as the currency.

Comment: The other, bigger problem is that it uses a comma instead of a decimal point!

Answer (score 8):

This is why you use different locale for different things.

In my case I mix en_GB and sv_SE to get what I need and it looks like this:

```
$> locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.utf8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.utf8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

But you would probably replace sv_SE with dk_DK.

And to get € use the LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8

I then save my config as a lot of exports in ~/.profile

```
export LC_MONETARY="en_IE.UTF-8"
```

This will give you the opportunity to pick the "correct" things from different areas.

Comment: I would in fact not replace `sv_SE` with `dk_DK` -- like I stated in my question, I picked Danish settings because they coincidentally and somewhat confusingly offered the features I wanted, even though I have no reason or desire to have anything specific to Denmark in my settings, and in fact, that is what I am trying to avoid.  Somewhat similarly, `sv_SE` makes (some sort of) sense for `LC_TIME` regardless of where in the world you are, because Sweden uses ISO dates by standard, unlike many other locales.

Comment: `LC_TIME=sv_SE.utf8` basically means that the names of weekdays and months will be unintelligible to non-speakers of Swedish. 

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I believe there is a locale that fits your requirements better than en_IE. It's unofficial, but it is [`en_SE.UTF-8`](http://www.stacken.kth.se/~auno/en_SE). That is a link which points to the locale file.

It basically copies sv-SE, which should get you everything you want (though I haven't double-checked), but gives you English system messages, menus, etc. I have used it before and it has worked very well for me in practice despite the caveats in the comment block at the top of the file.

To install:

1. download so that the locale file is accessible as `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_SE`
2. run `sudo localedef -i en_SE -f UTF-8 en_SE.UTF-8`
3. add to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` the line `en_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8` (might be different based on distribution; Debian Squeeze/6.0 seems to be happy with `/etc/locale.gen`)
4. run `sudo locale-gen`
5. set your system or account default locale to `en_SE.UTF-8` (for example, through `/etc/default/locale` on Debian-like systems)
6. reboot, or log off and back on, to activate the new locale

Comment: But Sweden didn't adopt €.

Comment: @mouviciel Did Ireland?

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eurozone.svg)

Comment: @mouviciel Drat, it does indeed look like [you are right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone#Member_states). So this doesn't fit the stated requirements perfectly either (strictly speaking neither does `en-IE` because of the numeric date format).

Comment: Also this has the definite drawback (along with `en_DK`) that it's a decidedly unobvious workaround for people not living in that particular country.  You could argue that `en_IE` doesn't completely pass that (additional) requirement, either; but at least it's possible to reason logically about the problem and reach that as a fair enough conclusion (although I had personally not reached it, based on multiple false assumptions about how things are done in Ireland).

Comment: Also, the locale travels with you when you `ssh` to remote systems, and you will get all sorts of annoying warnings if your locale is not installed on the remote system as well.

Comment: In fact, I have abandoned `en_IE` for now because I got tired of asking admins to set up this locale for me. While it's technically trivial, the everlasting hassle simply outweighs the convenience.

Comment: My terminal applications didn't like this locale, and trying to follow the directions just gave me a series of errors from localedef.  KDE seems to use en_SE fine though.

Answer (score 1):

I use `en_IE@euro ISO-8859-15`

```
$ export LC_MONETARY= "en_IE@euro ISO-8859-15"
```

... but I'm not exactly sure about measurements, considering using `nl_NL.UTF-8` or `nl_BE.UTF-8`, the only issue I have with that is once I allow for such a library other apps might end up using it as reference for local lib and again start to download apps and service in dutch or even german.

winetricks drove me up the wall last night with `vcrun6` even after changing the `locale-gen` removing any hint of German lib it still kept downloading a german version of `redistributablec++`, eventually did it manually, completely by launching the exe with wine.

Unbelievably I'm here again over the same issue; this time it's APT and the local Belgian repo hell bent on editing my locale config, it can't because I edited the permissions so instead I just get error complaints:

```
Fetched 207 kB in 0s (1381 kB/s)
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "nl_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_IE@euro ISO-8859-15",
    LC_ADDRESS = "nl_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "nl_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_MESSAGES = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "nl_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "nl_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

No compromise, all or nothing .. the only other solution would be to change repo I guess but I'll never be completely trouble free since the keyboard is an AZERTY and by law it only does French of Belgian Dutch .... :'(

Comment: That sounds weird. The `LC_MONETARY` or `LC_MEASUREMENT` settings are certainly not supposed to affect the message catalog language.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here mix language and region, with are **not** to be mixed. `en_US` means the American English variant, just as `en_IE` means the Irish English variant. It is perfectly fine to live in Hungary and use American English as a language.

The regional specifics are set with the other variables of locale, like `LC_TIME`, `LC_MONETARY`, etc.

For the lazy, and where language matches country, one can of course use `LANG` or `LC_ALL` to make the setting quicker.

There are some tries to have international English language and region, like `en_001`, `en_150`, but that is all broken. The language is not really defined (or, it is just `en_US`), and the regional settings do not try to get unambiguous. To give just two examples: these international English locale attempts still have comma as thousands separator, instead of using an unambiguous thin space or Arabic thousands separator (single quote), they still have traditional quotes and double quotes instead of open and close like Asian quotes or guillemets (「 」, « »).

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Do they use such special quotes in Europe, then? I see they have some advantage, though.

Comment: @jarno There are [many regional differences between the correct uses of quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Summary_table), but these are generally language-dependent, not locale-dependent. To write English in Germany you'd still use English quoting conventions, for example. I suspect the OP is actually trying to make a distinction between straight ASCII quotes (`'` and `"`) and proper typographical quotes (`‘’` and `“”`), or mixing up that criticism with a different and (to me, at least) more obscure one.

Answer (score -1):

See https://github.com/PanderMusubi/locale-en-nl for a proper English locale for the Netherlands, which is not possible to set by remixing existing locales by their LC_ environment settings.