# Unknown encoding: POSIX

Tags: character-encoding, x-resources

I'm trying to run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` but I'm getting the following error:

```
~/dotfiles/.Xresources:0: warning: Unknown encoding: POSIX
```

Any suggestions?

```
Xft.hinting: true 
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull 
Xft.antialias: rgba 
Xft.rgba: none
Xft.dpi: 96

Xcursor.theme: DMZ-Black
Xcursor.size: 16

#define r_bg   #000000
#define r_fg   #aaaaaa
#define r_hlfg #ffffff

! States: bg, fg, bgalt, hlbg, hlfg
rofi.color-enabled: true
rofi.color-normal: r_bg,r_fg,r_bg,r_bg,r_hlfg
rofi.color-urgent: r_bg,#ffffff,r_bg,r_bg,r_hlfg
rofi.color-active: r_bg,r_fg,#ffffff,r_bg,#ffffff
! states: background, border
rofi.color-window: r_bg,#ffffff

rofi.separator-style: solid
rofi.sidebar-mode: falseA
rofi.bw: 1
rofi.columns: 1
rofi.padding: 5

rofi.yoffset: -300
rofi.opacity: 80
rofi.fake-transparency: true
rofi.location: 0
rofi.width: 30
rofi.font: Inconsolata 12
rofi.lines: 10

! special
*.foreground:   #ffffff
*.background:   #000000
*.cursorColor:  #cc00ff

! black
*.color0:       #1c1c1c
*.color8:       #00d7ff

! red
*.color1:       #ff00ff
*.color9:       #d700ff

! green
*.color2:       #00afaf
*.color10:      #00afd7

! yellow
*.color3:       #0087af
*.color11:      #5f5fff

! blue
*.color4:       #5f5faf
*.color12:      #ff5fff

! magenta
*.color5:       #d75fff
*.color13:      #00d7ff

! cyan
*.color6:       #00afff
*.color14:      #00ffff

! white
*.color7:       #808080
*.color15:      #ccffff

! define different font params for various machines
#ifdef SRVR_chromebook
    #define urxvt_font_size 17
    #define urxvt_letter_spacing -1
#elif defined SRVR_baseline
    #define urxvt_font_size 16
    #define urxvt_letter_spacing -1
#else
    #define urxvt_font_size 15
    #define urxvt_letter_spacing -2
#endif

! make it easy to change font in one place
#define urxvt_font xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=urxvt_font_size
#define urxvt_bold_font urxvt_font:style=Bold

URxvt*font: urxvt_font
URxvt*boldFont: urxvt_bold_font

URxvt*allow_bold: true
URxvt*letterSpace: urxvt_letter_spacing

URxvt*buffered: false
URxvt.transparent: true
URxvt*shading: 15

URxvt*scrollBar:     false
```

Also, I'm having trouble getting 256 color support with urxvt, tmux, and vim

The output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=POSIX
```

I am running Fedora

Comment: For some reason it (some program) doesn't like the fact that you have `LC_ALL=POSIX`. Change it to a valid locale, either `C` or any appropriate locale reported by `locale -a`.

Comment: How do you change the locale? It looks like what I need to do is set a default locale in my `locale.conf`.

Comment: @ZacYauney Yes, in `/etc/locale.conf`.  See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration.html  I'm not on Fedora myself, so can't verify or reproduce any of this.

Comment: I would perhaps not change settings system-wide if this is only problematic with `xrdb` (and maybe a few other utilities with similar provenance).

Comment: For tangential background, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153556/consequences-of-setting-up-posix-locales

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily set a different locale for the duration of the `xrdb` command with

```
LC_ALL=C xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

I'm speculating that `xrdb` was compiled with some legacy library from many years ago which supports the basic locale API but doesn't know how to handle the POSIX locale. (You might want to submit a bug report with a link to this answer if this is reproducible. [Pertinent standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02) require POSIX to be defined, and behave identically to the the C locale.)

Comment: The C locale is not legacy.  The POSIX locale and the C locale are one and the same.

Comment: To my understanding, the reason there are two names with the same semantics is certainly for compatibility with legacy systems which used the older locale name C. But thanks for following up; I removed that pesky word from this answer.

Comment: C/POSIX has been there far longer than Fedora, making this answer not useful to anyone.  The problem is likely some breakage in the X locale configuration.

Comment: This solution actually helped my on Fedora 32, so its useful. I checked that the `.Xresources` file had no BOM.

Comment: The contents of the file are probably unimportant; the error message is saying that some internal API that the program is calling doesn't support the `POSIX` locale and so it's bailing out. You could perhaps `strace` or `ltrace` the bug to find the culprit.