# making a new locale file for Linux, and getting it accepted as a standard

Tags: locale

I am wanting to set up a new locale for "Indonesian English" (en_ID) for Linux systems.

While English is not widely spoken in Indonesia, it is still used widely in business and the professions.

I have made a new locale file using en_SG as a template, and then made several adjustments to the setup so that it conforms to Indonesian standards.  I use this locale for a Linux desktop distro that I support, and it works fine.

**What I wish to ask is, how can I establish this en_ID locale as a standard?  What should I do to to publish it, and where should I publish it? How do I open it up for scrutiny and suggestions for improvement?**

Comment: It would be `en_ID`, not `id_EN`. Locales are included with your libc, generally, so you'd want to get in touch with (probably) the glibc maintainers. You can see more about that [on their wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales). I'm not sure this question is really suitable on this site, though.

Comment: yes, should be en_ID. fixed.  thanks for the direction. ok, i shall look at glibc wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The [Unicode Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) is where you would submit your proposal; but I have serious doubts that they would accept it, especially given that they somewhat recently adopted `en_150` for organizations and systems operating in English in geographies where English is not the standard default language.

Comment: Kudos for this answer would properly belong to @snakeroot, who [answered a question of mine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158645/19240) with this information.